# Aggregating `bazel test` reports when testing many targets

Tags: bash, scala, junit, bazel

I am trying to aggregate all the `test.xml` reports generated after a `bazel test` run. The idea is to then upload this *full* report to a CI platform with a nicer interface.

**Consider the following example**

```sh
$ find .
foo/BUILD
bar/BUILD
$ bazel test //...
```

This might generate

```sh
./bazel-testlogs/foo/tests/test.xml
./bazel-testlogs/foo/tests/... # more
./bazel-testlogs/bar/tests/test.xml
./bazel-testlogs/bar/tests/... # more
```

I would love to know if there is a better way to aggregate these `test.xml` files into a single `report.xml` file (or the equivalent). This way I only need to publish 1 report file.

**Current solution**
The following is totally viable, I just want to make sure I am not missing some obvious built in feature.

```sh
find ./bazel-testlogs | grep 'test.xml' | xargs [publish command]
```

In addition, I will check out the JUnit output format, and see if just concatenating the reports is sufficient. This might work much better.